# Foundation 5 Responsive Offcanvas Menu

Tags: jquery, css, zurb-foundation

I am trying to make my self a off canvas responsive menu using foundation 5.

I would like to be able to show normal menu until it get to a certain break point but then uses the off canvas. But just using the one menu. Any ideas how?

```
<div class="off-canvas-wrap">
<div class="inner-wrap">
<nav>
<section class="small-left">
<a  class="left-off-canvas-toggle menu-icon"><span></span></a>
</section>
<ul>
<li><a href="">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="">Portfolio</a></li>
<li><a href="">Website Quotes</a></li>
<li><a href="">Open Cart Templates</a></li>
<li><a href="">Responsive HTML Templates</a></li>
<li><a href="">Tutorials</a></li>
<li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
<li><a href="">About</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean to show only one menu at the same time then see [Hide by Screen Size](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/visibility.html#hide-by-screen-size).

For example, use `.hide-for-small` class for normal menu and `.hide-for-medium`, `.hide-for-large` classes for off-canvas menu.